# "Local variable 'name_variable' value is not used" error in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I'm new to programming and I'm currently learning Python.
While trying to make a simple game, I got stuck when I tried to change the variable, named `user_answer` to `input("Please, answer with yes or no.")`.
Basically this is my line of code `else: user_answer = input("Please, answer with yes or no.")`.
But for some reason I get an error, called "Local variable 'user_answer' value is not used".
Could anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance!

Here's my full code:

```
def my_function():
    user_answer = input("Would you like to play a game?")
    if user_answer == "yes":
        print("Great! I have a number in my head from 1 to 10. Make a guess!")
    elif user_answer == "no":
        print("Oh, okay! Maybe next time?")
    else: user_answer = input("Please, answer with yes or no.")


my_function()
```

Comment: This is not a Python error, probably just a warning from your IDE. It's probably because you don't use `user_answer` anywhere beyond this point.

Comment: Please indicate which IDE you are using.

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing you're talking about an IDE inspection, not an actual runtime error? Are you using an IDE like PyCharm? If so, `local variable ... value not used` means that you are storing a value (`input(...)`) in a variable (`user_answer`) and then you're never using that value. But that is just as it should be, because it seems your program ends there; nothing is using the new value of `user_answer`.

Just ignore the warning  and continue writing your program, making sure to **use the new value of the variable**, and the warning should disappear.

For context, the purpose of this warning is to catch programming mistakes early on. Suppose that I wanted to write a function that takes a list and appends the element in the middle to either end (front and back), and I wrote this:

```py
def wrap_with_middle_element(sequence):
    mid = sequence[len(sequence)//2]
    sequence.append(element)
    sequence.insert(0, element)
    return sequence
```

You'll notice I didn't actually use the variable `mid` after defining it, but rather I used `element`. This could be because, for example, there is a global variable named `element` which the IDE suggested as code completion and I accepted absentmindedly, or because `mid` was previously named `element`, and in manually renaming it to `mid` (instead of using the IDE's functionality), I forgot to rename the other two appearances of the variable. (I know this seems kind of unlikely, but it's just to illustrate.) In this case the IDE will show the warning: `Local variable 'mid': value is not used`, since I'm defining `mid` but never using it. I'd quickly realise what was wrong and fix that (instead of finding out later when running the program).

---

## Working example of OP's code

```
def my_function():
    user_answer = input("Would you like to play a game? ")

    while user answer not in ('yes', 'no'):
        user_answer = input("Please, answer with yes or no. ")

    if user_answer == "yes":
        print("Great! I have a number in my head from 1 to 10. Make a guess!")
    elif user_answer == "no":
        print("Oh, okay! Maybe next time? ")


my_function()
```

In this example, first we get the user input with `user_answer = input("Would you like to play a game? ")` and then we make sure that it's either "yes" or "no" with the loop

```
while user_answer not in ('yes', 'no'):
        user_answer = input("Please, answer with yes or no. ")
```

which terminates only when `user_answer in ('yes', 'no')` (or, equivalently `user_answer == 'yes' or user_answer == 'no'`) evaluates to `True`.

Then you can continue with the rest of the program!

```
# if user_input...
```

### Why it didn't work

With your previous code, the `else` statement executed when the user didn't input a valid answer (`yes` or `no`). But the problem was that, once the user inputted a new value (which could have also been invalid!), the program had nowhere to go (it had already "left behind" the `if user_answer == "yes": print(...)` code!).

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the problem is that I'd like the program to print when the answer become "yes" or "no", that's why I want to change the input of `user_answer`

Comment: @Manu Correct me if I'm wrong; with the last `else` statement, you want the program to make sure the user inputs either `"yes"` or `"no"` but not something else like `"foo"`?

Comment: Dude, you saved my life!